# Почему wordpress загружает фото по http а не https

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, https

Почему wordpress загружает фото по http а не https? Сcылка фото будет начинаться на http, из-за чего у меня сайт "защищённые не полностью". Как это можно исправить?

Comment: где, что, когда?.. Вы хотите сказать что все вордпрессы показывают кривые ссылки?.. Что-то мне подсказывает что нет. И что-то мне подсказывает что проблема у Вас на сайте, возможно в теме или еще где-то. Но помочь с этим Вам никто никогда не сможет, потому что в вопросе нет примеров, ссылок и каких бы то ни было конкретных данных, на основании которых Вам можно было бы помочь. Поэтому постарайтесь дополнить свой вопрос, таким образом чтобы на него можно было дать ответ. Пока что это не представляется возможным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Нужно убедиться что в админке WP (`sitename.ru/wp-admin/options-general.php`) адрес сайта был указан с `https`.
2) Если картинки локальные (не загружаются со сторонних ресурсов) и первый пункт выполнен проверьте что в `<img src=` нет `http`
3) Если картинки удаленные (на стороннем ресурсе), нужно поправить ссылки на https. Если удаленный ресурс не поддерживает https - придется скачивать их на свой сайт, чтобы отдавать их по шифрованному каналу.